# Expect script not working in for loop for ssh

Tags: ssh, foreach, expect, spawn

I am trying to run expect script where it does foreach loop in hostnames, then does ssh into the nodes and take tech-support.  Each node has got variable time to produce output on tech-support.

```
Usage: 
  ./test.sh admin password

Filename: hostnames.txt
            node1
```

Script : test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set exp_internal 1
set timeout 4
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
set rootdir /home/$user
set f [open "$rootdir/hostnames.txt"]
set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f
log_user 1

foreach host $hosts {
 puts $host
 spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null "$user@$host"
 expect "*assword: "
 send "$password\r"
 expect "#"
 send "file md /TS/\r"
 expect "#"
 send "admin tech-support /TS/$host.ts1\r"
 expect "#"
 sleep 180
 expect "#"
 send "logout\r"
 expect eof
 close $spawn_id
}
```

Error I get is as below, there is only node in the hostnames.txt file, but it returns error once techsupport is completed in node1. so not sure if it is going to run for another node if added in hostnames.txt file

```
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null admin@
ssh: : Name or service not known
send: spawn id exp6 not open
while executing
"send "$password\r""
("foreach" body line x)
invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no -oUserKnownHost..."
(file "./test4.sh" line x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The split is giving you a list with two entries: the line in the hostnames.txt up to the newline and then an empty string that is after the newline.   You need to test if $host is a non-empty string.

Add another line to hostnames.txt and see that it behaves properly for the second host.  If you don't have another test node you want to try this on, instead add a duplicate line reading "node1" and see that both iterations of the loop do the same thing.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the update, i figured that out ....  i added a check in there "if {[string length $host] != 0 } " ....now atleast i dont get ssh error but i m still getting error "send: spawn id exp6 not open"

Comment: In the output you showed in the question it looked like $host was empty -- does that still seem to be the case?   And does it work properly for node1?  That's what I understood from your original question.

Is the "if {[string length $host] " ... part covering the whole body of the foreach loop, or just on the spawn command?   Sorry, I'm not entirely clear where this is left for you.

Comment: I am not sure why it pick up empty string ... i dont have any other entry other than node1 in that file .....now after putting that if check ..... i dont get error ... i put that if statement just before spawn within foreach loop....

Comment: Also, using `read -nonewline $fh` will remove the trailing newline from the last line.

Comment: @user3897774, using `puts "host=>$host<"` is a better tracing method to identify blank values or values ending with a carriage return (DOS-style line endings)